# Restore overwritten table in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

How can I restore accidentally overwritten table in BigQuery? I have tried to do a copy (`bq cp`) of a snapshot by timestamp previous to the overwritten timestamp but it does not work.

`bq cp my_table@1480406400000 new_table`

Answer (score 1):

This might be equivalent to [Undeleting a Table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#undeletetable%20for%20more) which is possible within two days (and performed on a best-effort basis and are not guaranteed)

Timestamp in your question looks like 3-4 days back - so that's might be an explanation

As an option try to **query** that snapshot and see if old data is still there.